# How to configure JMS listener in application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms

Following code doesn't work:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${myDestination}", containerFactory = "jmsContainerFactory")
public void receive(String message) {
    // do something
}
```

How to inject the value of `myDestination` defined in my *application.properties* file into the JmsListener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `application.properties`:

```
myDestination=myQueue
```

It probably doesn't work because you're using Spring Boot 1.3 that ships with Spring Framework 4.2. This got implemented as of Spring Framework 4.3.RC1 so you can override the version to `4.3.1.RELEASE` or give Spring Boot `1.4.0.M3` a try (the final will be available soon).